# How to work with DateTime.Now to ticks

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I'm trying to add the phones current time to my date time list. I need it to be able to subtract with the ticks. I have tried using `phonecurrentime.ToString("dd hh:mm");` but because it's a string there are no ticks and all sorts of errors!

I need it to work with `DateTime.now`.

Here is my code:

```
InitializeComponent();

List<DateTime> theDates = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime fileDate, closestDate;

theDates.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 29, 0));
theDates.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 3, 29, 0));
theDates.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 3, 29, 0));

// This is the date that should be found
theDates.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 4, 22, 0));

// This is the date you want to find the closest one to
fileDate = DateTime.Now;

long min = long.MaxValue;

foreach (DateTime date in theDates)
{
    if (Math.Abs(date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks) < min)
    {
        min = Math.Abs(date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks);
        closestDate = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: what type is phonecurrentime? does it even compile?

Comment: Seems like an [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: Please clarify your question. What EXACTLY the problem is, where you encountered problem ? and why you used `phonecurrentime.ToString("dd hh:mm")` why didn't you use `DateTime.Now` ?

Comment: It doesnt get the correct time when using datettime.now it always gets the largest number possible from the list instead of the correct result

Comment: @Jeremyc What is wrong with it? the largest date in your list(first item in your example) is the *closest* date.

Comment: if the closest time is 11:30 an the largest time on the list it will say its 17:00 for example where it should say 11:30

Comment: @Jeremyc I still don't understand. Your comment isn't clear.  You only want to compare the time component of date time?

Comment: I want it to find the time closest to the time of theDates. But its finding the largest time or the last time in the theDates list. If I end the time manually with: theDates.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 24, 39, 0)); It displays the correct match

Answer (score 1):

if you have a string and want to convert it to `DateTime` you can use

```
CultureInfo cf = new CultureInfo("en-us");

if(DateTime.TryParseExact("12 12:45", "dd hh:mm", cf, DateTimeStyles.None, out fileDate))
{
  // your code
}
```

and your code would look like:

```
    List<DateTime> theDates = new List<DateTime>();
    DateTime fileDate, closestDate;

    theDates.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 29, 0));
    theDates.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 3, 29, 0));
    theDates.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 3, 29, 0));

    // This is the date that should be found
    theDates.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 4, 22, 0));

    CultureInfo cf = new CultureInfo("en-us");
    string timeToParse = phonecurrentime.ToString("dd hh:mm");

    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(timeToParse, "dd hh:mm", cf, DateTimeStyles.None, out fileDate))
    {
        long min = long.MaxValue;

        foreach (DateTime date in theDates)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks) < min)
            {
                min = Math.Abs(date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks);
                closestDate = date;
            }
        }
     }
```

if you want to compare the time part of the dateTime you can use `TimeOfDay` property:

```
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        foreach (DateTime date in theDates)
        {
            long diff = Math.Abs(ts.Ticks - date.TimeOfDay.Ticks);

            if (diff < min)
            {
                min = diff;
                closestDate = date;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't actually need it to a string. I just need datetime.now to work with ticks. Will try

Comment: @Jeremyc if you look at the end of my answer you'll see that i work with DateTime.Now in ticks, and use only the time part of the DateTime

Answer (score 1):

Darren Davies above is correct.

You can add/subtract datetime objects. The result is of type `TimeSpan`, which lets you easily compare date and/or time differences.

Also, you should give a name to each date you add to your list (assign to a variable then add to list). A month later you won't remember what each day meant ;)

Comment: It won't work with datetime.now though

Answer (score 0):

```
fileDate = phonecurrentime.ToString("dd hh:mm");
```

Will not compile.  `fileDate` is a `DateTime` object.  You need to assign it to another `DateTime` object, not a `string`.

If `phonecurrenttime` is a `DateTime` you can ommit the .ToString() method.

```
fileDate = phonecurrenttime;
```

**Edit**

From your comment, if you simply want to assign the current ddate/time to `fileDate` you can use `DateTime.Now`:

```
fileDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: It won't work with datetime.now though

Comment: @Jeremyc - it will.  You need to do fileDate = DateTime.Now;

Comment: Doesn't get the closest time gets the bigger number instead. if the closest time is 11:30 an the largest time on the list it will say its 17:00 for example where it should say 11:30 – Jeremyc just now edit